# Return certain column from every row in a MySQL table in an array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So let's say this is the hierarchy of my database in MySQL.

```
Database: Example
  Table: Test
    Row 1
      Column 1 ("one"): Whatever
      Column 2 ("two"): Something
      Column 3 ("three"): Test
    Row 2
      Column 1  ("one"): Blah
      Column 2  ("two"): Testing
      Column 3  ("three"): Yup
```

How can I return an array that has the values of the `one` columns?

The array would look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Whatever [1] => Blah )
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code you have and where you are going wrong, *even if it does not work*. This will help give a directed answer that you can understand, rather than consuming our time trying to write a twenty-page tutorial or doing your work for you. For example, are you having trouble writing SQL queries, passing the information back to php, massaging the array, ...?

Comment: this is not going to solve you issue , please provide `show create table tablename` firstb and full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT column1 FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result); // should be 2

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $row[0]; // data from column
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I have no idea why it did and the others didn't. Thank you!

Comment: Remember, the query returns multiple results. You have to iterate over each of them.

Comment: I thought I was doing that, I guess I wasn't after all. Gah, I just spent the last hour or so trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think its simple.

```
select Column 1 From tablename;
```

Comment: I tried this but it's only returning `Column 1` from the first row.

Comment: Yes, when I looked this up, it seemed to do exactly what I needed except for some reason it isn't. Any idea what could be making it malfunction?

Answer (score 1):

Might be issue with the spaces. If there are spaces in column name use back quotes e.g

```
 select `Column 1` from tablename;
```

I am not sure your example depicts your actual problem :(

Comment: `select * from tablename where one="Blah"` is returning the second row without any issue, I don't get what's going on.

Comment: what is your actual data ?